# webgl : Quad wireframe remove the diagonal line

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

Using the braycentric method I am able get the wireframe drawn (ref: http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates/). What is the best way to discard the diagonal line using the shaders.

Comment: You're drawing triangles, not quads. There are no real diagonals, only apparent ones.

Comment: [This question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67002/how-can-i-draw-a-quad-in-wireframe-with-modern-opengl-without-rendering-the-int) should help you.

Comment: you need to somehow designate an edge to not be drawn (across two triangles). If you can filter this edge, you can just multiply the step thingie by 0 thus removing it.

Comment: pailhead: Since webgl does not have geometry shader I am having a tough time to figure out how this can be done using vertex and fragment shader only.

Comment: I don't understand why the question I linked you does not help you, Just generate and draw lines that represent the quads

Comment: @Zouch: Yes it did point me in the right direction to draw only the outlines as mentioned in answers. May be I didn't state the issue properly, sorry. The object to be drawn could be a mix of quads and trias. So here is what I am looking into right now, as pointed out by pailhead find if the vertex is on hypotenuse and discard it.

Comment: You should edit your question and clarify it. Give an example of what you want to do and what you want to achieve.